# Plotting the function $\frac{x-1}{1+e^{\frac{1}{x-1}}}$

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions, curves

I tried plotting the function $\frac{x-1}{1+e^{\frac{1}{x-1}}}$. For this I tried to gather information as follows:

1. The curve doesn't pass through origin.
2. When $x \rightarrow +\infty$, $y \rightarrow +\infty$
3. When $x \rightarrow -\infty$, $y \rightarrow -\infty$
4. When $x=0, y=-0.73$ and when $y=0, x=1$.

With this information, I drew this graph
[image]

To check if it is right, I plotted on [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/oazvnop6en) and it seems **different**. So I decided to go further.

5. To find the point of maxima/minima, inflection, I tried calculating the first and second derivative,
   \begin{equation*}
   \begin{split}
   y' &= \frac{1+e^{\frac{1}{x-1}}+e^{\frac{1}{x-1}}\times\frac{1}{x-1}}{(1+e^{\frac{1}{x-1}})^2}
   \end{split}
   \end{equation*}
6. To find maxima or minima, I have to equate $y'=0$

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
1+e^{\frac{1}{x-1}}+e^{\frac{1}{x-1}}\times\frac{1}{x-1} &= 0\\
x-1 + x e^{\frac{1}{x-1}}  &= 0
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

How to solve this equation for value of $x$?
From the graph on desmos, there is indeed a tangent with slope $0$ at the interval $[1,1.3]$. And believe it should be solvable.

7. To find the concavity direction, I know I have to evaluate $y''$. But it gets messier to have $y''$. From the graph on desmos again, the curve is concave upward both on the left and right of $x=1$.

Any help on how to solve points $6$ and $7$?

Comment: You have the same "graph" as desmos with the information are given, it's only the discontinuity in the derivative at $x=1$ you didn't encapsulate. But as an instructor, I wouldn't have expected you to take single sided limits on the derivative had this been a first year calculus exam problem to sketch the graph.

Comment: The algebra and handwritten work is slightly simpler if you analyze/plot the graph of $\frac{x}{1 + \exp(1/x)}$ and then shift the graph horizontally to the right by $1$ unit (recall school precalculus graph shifting results).

Comment: See pp. 276-277 of [**An Elementary Treatise on the Differential Calculus Founded on the Method of Rates Or Fluxions**](https://archive.org/details/anelementarytre05johngoog/page/n297/mode/2up) by John Minot Rice and William Woolsey Johnson (1888 reprint of 1877 edition) (also pp. 55-56 of [this google-books version](https://books.google.com/books?id=V3uwUJw_OqEC&pg=PA55#v=onepage&q&f=false)). Incidentally, many freely available 1800s texts, such as this one, have a lot of material that is mostly unknown today.